# how to make constant, looping animation?

Tags: animation, looping

I just want to make some object rotate in a loop, with no interpolation curve things making it "smooth", just want it to go at the same speed all the time. How do I do this? I've made some keyframes but it always slows down/stops for a really short time at the end..

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are multiple reasons why this could be happening.
The first one is: You dont have linear interpolation
The fix for that is:

1. Go into the Graph Editor
2. Press <kbd>V</kbd> and select Vector

The second one is: your animation ends on the wrong frame or starts at the wrong frame. Make sure your last keyframe which is the same as the first one is never actually shown (or the other way round), because when it is, you have 2 exactly equal frames played in sequence. In practice that means you have to either put your first keyframe at frame 0 and start on the frame 1 and end at the last keyframe. Or you put your start and first keyframe on frame 1 and set the end to be 1 frame before the last keyframe.

Comment: very quick answer, but this didnt fix it

Comment: make sure your previously made animation is selected in the Graph Editor (press A multiple times)

Comment: did my edit fix it?

Comment: sorry for the late reply: where am i supposed to cut the animation off? do i stop it a frame before the last keyframe (which is both the end and beginning pose)? if i do that it still slows down at the end, am i supposed to stop it somewhere else?

Comment: [this is what it looks like right now btw](https://gyazo.com/d5ce18c1e5bd41d816df7c31a7a33583) (i set it to start on frame 1 because i accidentally made the 1st keyframe there and not at 0)

Comment: @MeowMilk yes you are supposed to cut it off one frame before your last keyframe. If that is not the fix post a screenshot of your grapheditor in your question.